# ASP .NET Web API Returning JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a ASP.NET Web API service end point where it queries the Oracle Database and returns the result in JSON format.

Below is the code I am using in the Controller

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
  public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
  {
    using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=J;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T"))
    {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(" + srtcon + ")";
        OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(selectResults);
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
        string contentDisposition = "inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json";
        //byte[] byteInfo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition);
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = byteInfo.Length;
        return response;
 }
}
```

Everything works fine, except that it returns result is in the below format

> "[{\"CATEGORY\":\"Internal
>   Study\",\"SESSION_NUMBER\":7,\"SESSION_START_DATE\":\"2015-02-13T00:00:00\",\"SESSION_START_TIME\":\"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394\",\"SESSION_END_DATE\":\"2015-02-13T00:00:00\",\"SESSION_END_TIME\":\"2015-02-13T12:11:34\"}]"

It is just that it creates the extra quotes and the extra escaping characters (`\`). Do I need to do the manipulation to have them removed.

> [{"CATEGORY":"Internal
>   Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_START_TIME":"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394","SESSION_END_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_END_TIME":"2015-02-13T12:11:34"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are already serializing the data to JSON and then trying to return it as `application/json` which only results in the formatter converting your string into a JSON formatted string.

So basically your are serializing the object to json string

> [{"CATEGORY":"Internal Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_START_TIME":"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394","SESSION_END_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_END_TIME":"2015-02-13T12:11:34"}]

and then serializing the json string to a serialized json string

> "[{\"CATEGORY\":\"Internal
>   Study\",\"SESSION_NUMBER\":7,\"SESSION_START_DATE\":\"2015-02-13T00:00:00\",\"SESSION_START_TIME\":\"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394\",\"SESSION_END_DATE\":\"2015-02-13T00:00:00\",\"SESSION_END_TIME\":\"2015-02-13T12:11:34\"}]"

Remove..

```
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
```

... and just pass the `selectResults` object as it is to the response and the formatter will do the rest based on the media type.

```
//...other code removed for brevity

var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, selectResults, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition)) {
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
}
return response;
```

If for example you changed the medial type to xml the response will be returned as xml.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi I am getting error in contentDisposition in `response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition);` i tried using System.Net.Mime but still shows the same error